# Unable to launch the browser using testng using beforeTest annotation

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, cucumber, testng

```
 I have used cucumber BDD for my testcases with testng as the test engine. I have added the necessary jars in my POM.xml as mentioned below. I am using selenium 2.53 and using Firefox browser.

<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>        

In runner class I have inherited the `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests` as below :      

        package com.cucumber.bhsibase.runner;        
        import org.junit.runner.RunWith;        
        import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
        import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
        import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;        
        @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
        @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources", glue = "com.cucumber.bhsibase.party.tests")
        public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {       
        }

I want to launch the browser with the url, so I have added that part of the code in a method with `@BeforeTest` annotation, but nothing happens. Tried the same using `@BeforeCLass` too, but it's the same.

Please find the code below: 

        public class PartyBase {

            // public static WebDriver driver;

            ReadXML readxmlobj = new ReadXML();

            final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PartyBase.class);


            ConfigReader reader = new ConfigReader();
            public static WebDriver driver;

        @BeforeTest
            public void geturl() throws Exception {
                logger.info("Entering the execute message");

                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                logger.info("Mozzilla Browser opens");
                driver.get(reader.readurls("ExpressURL"));
                logger.info("Navigate to express");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }

Please let me know how to proceed ahead with this. The code runs fine only if the method is called explicitly in the given step definition of each scenarios.    
 This issue is same if I use `@before` annotation of Junit as well.
```

My Testng.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Party" parallel="none">
<test name = "Base Party Validation">
<classes>
<class name ="com.cucumber.bhsibase.runner.TestRunner"></class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

I have added just my testrunner class . I was under the impression that irrespective of the class added in the testng.xml , the beforetest annotation will be run before other methods . Unable to proceed ahead . Do I need to add any other classes inside the testng.xml .

Comment: Also this is my testng.xml file :
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Party" parallel="none">
<test name = "Base Party Validation">
<classes>
<class name ="com.cucumber.bhsibase.runner.TestRunner"></class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the xml? It'll be easier to read. Thanks

Comment: have added in the question .

Comment: The code sample in this repo might be helpful for you https://github.com/igniteram/testng-cucumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suite xml contains reference to only the `TestRunner` class, but it looks like your annotated configuration methods reside in a different class (`PartyBase` in your case) which isn't being included in the suite xml file.

So you have two options:

1. You can include `PartyBase` also in your suite xml file (or)
2. move those annotations into your `TestRunner` class itself.